# On-topic post closed as off-topic

Tags: support, specific-question, off-topic, reopen-closed

[Artifactory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_repository#Repository_managers) has:

1. A tag on Stack Overflow
2. A programmable [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) API

The question *[How do I download the latest artifact from Artifactory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13989033/how-do-i-download-the-latest-artifact-from-artifactory)* was closed as off-topic. IMO, it is not. Can it be re-opened?

Comment: It seems to be on-topic to me. It's not a great question, a little broad, but certainly on topic. I've voted to re-open.

Comment: It's been reopened now, but my guess on why it was closed originally is it reads very much like a recommendation question (i.e. shopping question)